# Threads in C - Textbook answer about multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

I have pulled a question from [Operating Systems - Internals and Design Principles Eighth Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0133805913).

I have tried my answer but really would like to know the proper response to this question.

> Considering the following C declarations and function definition:
>
> ```
> int global_positives = 0;
> typedef struct list { 
>    struct list *next;
>    double val;
> } *list;
>
> void count_positives(list l)
> {
>   list p;
>   for (p = 1; p; p = p -> next)
>      if (p -> val > 0.0)
>         ++global_positives;
> }
> ```
>
> While thread A does:
>
> ```
> count_positives(<list containing only negative numbers>);
> ```
>
> and thread B does:
>
> ```
> ++global_positives;
> ```
>
> a) what does the function do?
>   b) The C language only addresses single threaded execution. Does the use of two parallel threads create any problems?

So my answers I would like to know if correct are:

a) The function as of now will do nothing in the case of thread A calling the function with only negative numbers since nothing will be greater than zero as well as...

b) the problem of having two threads run in parallel in C because since only one can run at a time global_positives will never increment and the answer will always be zero.

In the ballpark?

Comment: Your answer for b is incorrect. Multiple threads can run at the same time on a multi-core machine. Even on a single core machine, the OS will pause thread A and run thread B every so often. However, since thread A doesn't access the shared `global_positives` variable (because the if condition in it always fails), only thread B will access `global_positives`, so there won't be any concurrency issues.

Comment: A number of typos there: *list should read list, p = 1 (one) should read p = l (el), p -> xyz should be p->xyz.

Comment: @jamrod: you can put spaces around `->` if you want to. I don't know anyone who does, but it's certainly legal.

Comment: there are no typos, this is directly from the textbook

Comment: I beg to differ. `(p = 1;` is *definitely* wrong. If not a typo on your part, notify the publisher and amend the errata, because a pointer being assigned the value of `1` (one) is utterly wrong.

Comment: For the sake of the problem can you explain if using these threads in parallel causes any problems if the syntax was correct?

Comment: You deduction based on the statement "... because since only one can run at a time.." is where the wheels falls off. That simply isn't true. True concurrent threads is a commonality with modern multi-core hardware and MPS os'es. The reason there is no currency issue *here* is solely because only two threads are running, and due to circumstance one will never modify otherwise-potentially-contentious shared data, *even if both threads are actively running simultaneously*. Run two instances of `B` and you have a recipe for disaster.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to `typedef` pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).  Succinctly, the primary answer is "No, it isn't".  Completely separately, there is either a typo in the question or in the book.  The `p = 1;` in the loop is erroneous in and of itself, and it also means that `l`, the function parameter, is unused.  It is undoubtedly intended to be `p = l;` (where the distinction is between digit one and letter lower-case ell).  This is rehashing what was already said in other comments — but the unused parameter wasn't mentioned.

Comment: Also notice that C11 does discuss multi-threaded execution.

Comment: @user3037172 There is no answer. C doesn't say what the rules for concurrent threads are. You'd have to check the appropriate documentation for the threading standard you happen to be using, and you don't mention what that standard might be.

Answer (score 0):

a)
count positives, does not update global positive count, and hence the two threads operate
on distinct global data, and require no locking.

b)
In a single-threaded environment,
it is consistent. However, in a multithreaded environment, it assigns to global positive count, even if the list contains
only negative elements. Our original program is now broken, since the update
of global positive count by thread B may be lost, as a result of thread A
writing back an earlier value of global positive count. By Pthread rules,
a thread-unaware compiler has turned a perfectly legitimate program into one
with undefined semantics.